# Mahout Hive Integration

Tags: hadoop, hive, mahout

I want to combine Hadoop based Mahout recommenders with Apache Hive.So that My generated Recommendations are directly stored in to my Hive Tables..Do any one know similar tutorials for this..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hadoop based Mahout recommenders can store the results in HDFS directly.

Hive also allows you to create table schema on top of any data using `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE recommend_table` which also specifies the location of the data (`LOCATION '/home/admin/userdata';`).

This way you are ensured that when new data is written to that location - `/home/admin/userdata` then it is already available to Hive and can be queried by existing `Table` schema : recommend_table.

I had blogged about it some time back: [external-tables-in-hive-are-handy](http://pyfunc.blogspot.com/2012/03/external-tables-in-hive-are-handy.html). This solution helps for any kind of map-reduce program output that needs to be available immediately for Hive ad-hoc queries.

Comment: How about if I want perform analysis with Mahout by reading data directory from Hive (i.e. through HQL)? All my tables are external tables. Thanks.